# GDI+ Image::SetPropertyItem not working as expected

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

I am trying to use `SetPropertyItem` to set a Date Taken property to a file ([click here for MSDN docs description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-reading-and-writing-metadata-use)).

I have tried assigning a newly initialized `FILETIME` to an input image with no success (or error messages). To ensure that it was not an issue with Date Taken, I also tried following [this MSDN example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusheaders/nf-gdiplusheaders-image-setpropertyitem) to no avail.

Currently, I am attempting to extract a Date Taken property item from one input file (works fine) and attempting to set it to a different file. This approach does not work either, and the `Status` code returned is always 0 (Ok).

The code I am using is below. I can only assume I am making a simple mistake or perhaps misunderstanding what `SetPropertyItem` is supposed to do. I thought that `SetPropertyItem` changed the metadata value such that it can be viewed through the Windows properties menu, like in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTx3c.png).

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace Gdiplus;

#pragma comment(lib, "gdiplus.lib")

int main()
{
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    Image* image = new Image(L"FakePhoto.jpg"); // input image

    UINT totalBufferSize;
    UINT numProperties; // setup the buffer
    image->GetPropertySize(&totalBufferSize, &numProperties);

   // extract all metadata property items
   PropertyItem* pAllItems = (PropertyItem*)malloc(totalBufferSize);
   image->GetAllPropertyItems(totalBufferSize, numProperties, pAllItems);

   for (UINT j = 0; j < numProperties; ++j)
   { // loop through each property
       if (pAllItems[j].id == PropertyTagExifDTOrig)
       { // if it's the Date Taken property
            PropertyItem* propItem = new PropertyItem;
            Image* newImage = new Image(L"Test2.jpg");
            Status status; // second image

            propItem->id = PropertyTagExifDTOrig;
            propItem->length = pAllItems[j].length;
            propItem->type = PropertyTagTypeASCII;
            propItem->value = pAllItems[j].value;
            // create a new property item with the input photo Date Taken metadata
            status = newImage->SetPropertyItem(propItem);

            if (status == Ok)
                std::cout << "No errors.";
        }
    }

    free(pAllItems);
    delete image;
    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Also, I apologise about any obvious/potential errors. I am still learning the ropes as this is my first time using C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code works fine, but you must save the image back, for example like this

```
...
newImage->SetPropertyItem(propItem);

CLSID clsid;
GetEncoderClsid(L"image/jpeg", &clsid);
newImage->Save(L"Test2.jpg", &clsid);
...

BOOL GetEncoderClsid(const WCHAR* format, CLSID* pClsid)
{
    UINT num = 0;
    UINT size = 0;
    ImageCodecInfo* info = NULL;

    ZeroMemory(pClsid, sizeof(CLSID));
    GetImageEncodersSize(&num, &size);
    if (size == 0)
        return FALSE;

    info = (ImageCodecInfo*)(malloc(size));
    if (info == NULL)
        return FALSE;

    GetImageEncoders(num, size, info);
    for (UINT j = 0; j < num; ++j)
    {
        if (!wcscmp(info[j].MimeType, format))
        {
            *pClsid = info[j].Clsid;
            free(info);
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    free(info);
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @simon. I had tried this previously and it did not work, but I am happy to report your solution does. However, it only works if the file being saved has a different name to the input file, i.e., Test3.jpg. If attempted with the input file, a Status error code of 7 is thrown. Once again, thanks for the help! :)